# OpenERP 7 TypeError: float_round() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rounding_method'

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am encountering the following error in OpenERP 7 while attempting to deliver a sales order on click of the Deliver button. I am only using out of the box functionalities and didn't do any custom build. Any suggestions how to fix this error?

> Client Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1132, in call_button
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send
>
> Server Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 199, in execute
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\stock\wizard\stock_partial_picking.py", line 193, in do_partial
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\product\product.py", line 171, in _compute_qty
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\product\product.py", line 183, in _compute_qty_obj
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\idataFiveERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\product_common.py", line 32, in ceiling
>   TypeError: float_round() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rounding_method'

Answer (score 0):

use the link https://github.com/OCA/OCB/issues/65 to update the file, and restart the service, that works for me.